# Identifying mention on a comment and populating data frame

Tags: r, twitter, twitter-r

I'm trying to get mentions on twitter data like @someone @somebody from a data frame twitter and creating a new data frame with the information of who tweeted and which people they mentioned.

Example:

```
tweets <- data.frame(user=c("people","person","ghost"),text = c("Hey, check this out 
@somebody @someone","love this @john","amazing"))
```

Resulting on this data frame:

```
**user     text**

*people   Hey, check this out @somebody @someone*

*person   love this @john*

*ghost    amazing*
```

The desired result is:

```
**id      mention**

*people  @somebody*

*people  @someone*

*person  john*

*ghost*
```

Can you guys help me , please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this by using library `stringr`:

```
library(stringr)
tweets$mention <- str_extract_all(tweets$text, '\\@\\S+')
```

Output is as follows:

```
tweets

    user                                     text             mention
1 people Hey, check this out \n@somebody @someone @somebody, @someone
2 person                          love this @john               @john
3  ghost                                  amazing
```

To get the output in long format, you can do something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
tweets <- rbind(filter(tweets, !grepl('\\@', mention)), unnest(tweets))
tweets <- tweets[, -2]
```

Output is as follows:

```
    user   mention
1  ghost          
2 people @somebody
3 people  @someone
4 person     @john
```